# Duda sobre escribir un fichero de forma aleatoria

Tags: java

```
    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

    public class Jugadores {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //declaramos objeto jugador
    Jugadores jugador = new Jugadores();
    //apertura del fichero
    RandomAccessEjercicio Apertura = new RandomAccessEjercicio("C:\\Users\\FER\\Downloads\\jugadores.txt","rw");
    //creamos el fichero
    Apertura.crearFichero();
    //declaramos el objeto
    RandomAccessFile objeto2;
    //conseguimos el objeto random a traves del metodo get object
    objeto2=Apertura.getObj();
    //escribimos el array
    jugador.escribirArrayFichero(objeto2);

}

public void escribirArrayFichero(RandomAccessFile param) throws IOException {
    String[] jugadores = {"jugador 1 ","jugador 2","jugador 3","jugador 4","jugador 5"};
    String[] apellidos = {"Garcia","nuñez","Gomez","Nuñez","Rios"};
    String[] equipo = {"Real Madrid","Atletic","Barcelona ","Betis","Sevilla"};
    String[] posicion = {"central","lateral","delantero","portero","Extremo"};
    int[] edad = {18,21,19,20,22};
    int i = 0;
    param.writeBytes("NOMBRE");
    param.writeBytes("\r\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {;
    param.writeBytes("\r\n"+jugadores[i]);
    }
    param.writeBytes("\n\r");
    param.writeBytes("\n"+"APELLIDOS");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {;
    param.writeBytes("\r\n"+apellidos[i]);
    }
    param.writeBytes("EQUIPO");
    param.writeBytes("\r\n");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {;
    param.writeBytes("\r\n"+equipo[i]);
    }
    param.writeBytes("\n\r");
    param.writeBytes("\n"+"APELLIDOS");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {;
    param.writeBytes("\r\n"+posicion[i]);
    }
    param.writeBytes("\n\r");
    param.writeBytes("\n"+"EDAD");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++) {;
    param.writeBytes("\r\n"+edad[i]);
    }

}

}
```

No me escribe los campos de forma correcta en el fichero, ejemplo:

```
NOMBRE APELLIDOS EQUIPO POSICION EDAD
 x        x        x       x       x
 x        x        x       x       x
 x        x        x       x       x
 x        x        x       x       x
 x        x        x       x       x
```

lo he intentado con el metodo `seek` pero me sigue escribiendo de manera horizontal, se que es una matriz y que debería hacer un array de dos posiciones pero no se como realmente hacerlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

creo que se podría hacer con un for, ya que los datos los quieres mostrar en una fila como indicas.

```
public void escribirArrayFichero(RandomAccessFile param) throws IOException {
    String[] jugadores = {"jugador 1 ","jugador 2","jugador 3","jugador 4","jugador 5"};
    String[] apellidos = {"Garcia","nuñez","Gomez","Nuñez","Rios"};
    String[] equipo = {"Real Madrid","Atletic","Barcelona ","Betis","Sevilla"};
    String[] posicion = {"central","lateral","delantero","portero","Extremo"};
    int[] edad = {18,21,19,20,22};
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        param.writeBytes(jugadores[i] + "\t" + apellidos[i] + "\t" + equipo[i] + "\t" + posicion[i] + "\t" + edad[i] +"\r\n");    
    }
 }
```

Espero que te sirva, lo he probado y te muestro el resultado por consola:

```
jugador 1   Garcia  Real Madrid     central 18
jugador 2   nu?ez   Atletic     lateral 21
jugador 3   Gomez   Barcelona       delantero   19
jugador 4   Nu?ez   Betis       portero 20
jugador 5   Rios    Sevilla     Extremo 22
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfeccion!, te doy la respuesta como correcta y tick arriba.